# jwt token return null

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

i try to get a user id by token,
the token is pass by the header Authorization,
when i use ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("jwt")(req)
i get back the token as null

here is pass the token to the header.

```
const token = localStorage.getItem("id_token");

export const insertMovie = (payload) => {
  return api.post(`/movie`, payload, {
    headers: { "Authorization": `${token}` },
  });
};
```

here i try to verify to token

```
var User = require("../models/user-model");
var Movie = require("../models/movie-model");
var bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
var jsonwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
var key = require("../db/myUrl");
var ExtractJwt = require("passport-jwt");



 createMovie = async (req, res) => {
  const movieDetails = req.body.movie;
  const token = ExtractJwt.ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("jwt")(req);
  const decoded = jsonwt.verify(token, key.secret);
  const userId = decoded.userId;
  console.log(decoded);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to

```
ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("jwt")
```

you need to add the token to the header like so:

```
headers: { "Authorization": `jwt ${token}` },
```

from the [docs](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/):

> fromAuthHeaderWithScheme(auth_scheme) creates a new extractor that looks for the JWT in the authorization header, expecting the scheme to match auth_scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve doubled up ExtractJwt but also if you’re declaring a scheme “jwt” that needs to be appended to the token
headers: `` { Authorization: `jwt ${token}` } ``

Otherwise change fromAuthHeaderWithScheme to just fromAuthHeader to `fromHeader(‘Authorization')`

Also I’m not sure if you can use passport directly inside an endpoint like this - I always thought it needed to be used as middleware.